# php mysql query to join two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've spent a long time today looking through SO and have yet to find an answer that I've implemented that works as I need and as this is the first time I've tried to join tables rather than create inefficient monsters, I thought I'd ask for help!

I have two tables:

1. userData (id, surname, email)
2. appointmentData (id, uid, appointmentNum, appointmentDate)

The uid in the second table corresponds with the id of the first table.

What I would like to do is display a table:

surname | email | appointment1 | appointment1 date | appointment2 | appointment2 date etc...

I tried:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userData as table1 INNER JOIN appointmentData as table2 ON table1.id = table2.uid ORDER BY table1.surname ASC");
```

But this will only display the first appointment for that particular user, if I use a while loop (I think I'm trying to display the data horizontally in the table when it's vertically in the array, if that makes sense):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo"<td>".$row['surname']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$row['apptDate']."</td>";
...
}
```

I'd really appreciate if someone could help point me in the right direction!

Comment: what should be displayed if one user has 1000000 appointments and another user has only 1 appointment?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, there is a maximum of three appointments, so I expect that if there is no appointment date set, I will need to display a blank table cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can start with:

```
$prevId = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['id'] != $prevId) {
        if ($prevId != '') echo '</tr>'; // close previous row
        echo '<tr><td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['surname']) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . '</td>';
        $prevId = $row['id'];
    }
    echo '<td>' . $row['apptDate'] . '</td>';
}
if ($prevId != '') echo '</tr>'; // close last row
```

this will display table you needed, but table layout will not be very correct (browser will display properly, but actual html code will not be right)

to fix this - you need to count how many columns were displayed and add appropriate number of empty `<td></td>` before closing `</tr>`

Comment: Ilya, you're a star! I'll need to go through as you say and sort the counts but you've helped me more in the past 10 minutes, than I've managed to achieve in the past 5 hours. Thank you so much, I've ticked the answer to accept it (let me know if there's anything else I need to do).

Just in case anyone else uses this answer by the way, the line:
    $prevName = $row['surname']
needs a semi-colon on the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

  $query="SELECT * FROM userData as table1 INNER JOIN appointmentData as table2 ON table1.id = table2.uid ORDER BY table1.surname ASC";
 $result=mysql_query($query);
 echo "table";
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo '<tr><td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['surname']) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['email']) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['appointment1 ']) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['date ']) . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a row for each record you must include a `<tr>` tag this way:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<tr>";
echo"<td>".$row['surname']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$row['apptDate']."</td>";
...
echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: I cut down on the code for brevity - the lack of <table>, <thead>, <th>, <tbody> etc... tags aren't the issue unfortunately - it's the way I'm pulling from the data. I didn't want to display the whole page, as it added no value to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The point here is that you have multiple appointments for one user and I'm thinking the "inner join" isn't the one you need if you're looking for what I said before. Try using outer join for multiple rows for each user.

This might help http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userData ORDER BY table1.surname ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appointmentData WHERE uid = {$row['id']} LIMIT 3");
    $appointment1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $appointment2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $appointment3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
    echo "<td>" . (($appointment1==false)?"":$appointment1['appointmentDate']) . "</td>";
}
```

I'm writing this on my phone, but maybe you got my idea.